# Error : Element should have been "select" but was "a"

Tags: selenium-webdriver

When i am trying to select an option from dropdown list i am getting the error "Element should have been "select" but was "a" " 
Below is my source code :

```
WebElement element= dr.findElement(By.id("m1tlm0"));
Select select=new Select (element);
select.selectByVisibleText("News");`
```

HTML Code :

```
<a id="m1tlm0" onmouseover="exM(m1,'m1mn3','m1tlm0',event)"     onmouseout="coM(m1,'m1mn3')" href="about-us.html">Introduction & Profiles</a>
```

Options are as below :

```
<div id="null" visibility: hidden;">Donation</div>
<div id="null" visibility: hidden;">Detailing</div>
<div id="null" visibility: hidden;">News</div>
<div id="null" visibility: visible;">Jobs</div>
<div id="null" visibility: visible;">Awards & Memberships</div>
<div id="null" After Sales Service</div>
<div id="null" visibility: visible;">Customization Facilities</div>
<div id="null" visibility: hidden;">IT Software Services</div>
<div id="null" visibility: hidden;">Corporate Presentation</div>
<div id="null" visibility: hidden;">Corporate Brochure</div>
```

Comment: Are these options getting visible after mouse over on `a` element or after click on `a` element??

Answer (score 4):

That's because this element is not `<select>` but `<a>` :)

When you find element with `findElement(By.id("m1tlm0"));` click on it. I assume that then list of options will appear. Then select one with `By.linkText` or `By.xpath` and `click()` on it.

Answer (score 1):

The `Select` class only works with `<select>` tags that contain `<option>` tags. If you have any other tag, it doesn't matter if it behaves like a `<select>` would, it will be rejected.

The error is telling you this. You are giving it an `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is coming because your XPath is pointing to something else, try to find the XPath of a select element and then use select class functions to select respective values from a drop-down.